# Is "with a decade of solid experience" correct?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

In the following sentence I wonder if ***with*** correct or I should use ***having*** or a better alternative?

> I am a web developer ***with/having*** a decade of experience in
>   web technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition "with" also means possessing or having. So the OP can use having or with in the sentence presented, without any difference in meaning.